# Trying to use Ternary operators with WP Conditionals

Tags: php, conditional-content, conditional-tags

Hi I am trying to use ternary operators with [WordPress condtionals](http://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags), using the code below, but it's giving me a PHP error, what am I doing wrong?

```
echo is_home() : '1' ? '0';
```

Answer (score 6):

Syntax is wrong you need to phrase it like so:

```
condition ? TRUE : FALSE
```

so change your code to :

```
echo is_home() ?  '1' : '0';
```

Comment: @Jhon: Glad i could help.

Answer (score 1):

In this particular case you could even shorten it to:

```
echo (int) is_home();
```